# Vue page transition with Vue-Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to make nice page transitions using Vue and Vue-Router.

I load different pages (components) directly in the **router-view**, these have a nice animation.

I've already got a great animation for all my pages, however I need to figure out how to simply change the transition based on the router-link that is clicked.

**If class of route-link is special, do another animation.**

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/1">Page 1</router-link>
      <router-link to="/2">Page 2</router-link>
      <router-link to="/3">Page 3</router-link>
      <router-link class="special" to="/4">Page 4</router-link>
    </nav>
    <transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave">
      <router-view/>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...
    methods: {
      enter(el, done) {
        // main page animation with a timeline using Greensock
      },
      leave(el, done) { 
        // main page animation with a timeline using Greensock
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

How do I get this to work?

**If the user clicks on router-link with a class of special, change**

```
<transition @enter="enter" @leave="leave">
  <router-view/>
</transition>
```

**to:**

```
<transition @enter="enterSpecial" @leave="leaveSpecial">
  <router-view/>
</transition>
```

**so that I can add**

```
    methods: {
      enter(el, done) {
        // main page animation with a timeline using Greensock
      },
      leave(el, done) { 
        // main page animation with a timeline using Greensock
      }
    },
```

I've searched through the docs + googled, and haven't found anything that could help.

Comment: can you share any live demo?

Comment: Unfortunately not really. I've over simplified the code here, the actual code is very different.. I just need to find a way to do another transition based on what router-link is clicked.

The actual special router-links are in child components. I've tried to use @click.native on the router-links to execute a function (to change the vuex state, that could help me change the animation), but then it stops the actual redirect of the link.

Comment: No problem, I personally needed live demo to make sure that given answer is working or not. But still I am sure every situation of vuejs can be share by part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Router Meta Fields to know which animation you should apply.
On routes declaration, you can add meta fields for each route. E.g:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/default',
      component: SomeComponent
    },
    {
      path: '/special',
      component: SomeComponent2,
      // meta fields
      meta: { 
          animation: 'special'
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Then on your components, you can do this:

```
 methods: {
   enter(el, done) {
     if (this.$route.meta.animation === 'special') {
         // apply special animation
     } else {
        // main page animation with a timeline using Greensock
     }
   },
   leave(el, done) { 
     // main page animation with a timeline using Greensock
   }
 }
```

You can find more information about vue-router meta fields [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is definitely heading in the right direction. The only problem I would have with this is that I have 3 ways each components could be animated in: regular, from the right, from the left. I'm creating a portfolio section, with components (projects), that could be loaded by clicking on the router-link (regular transition), clicking on the "next project" router-link (transition from the right), or previous project (transition from the left).. Do you have any idea how I could detect the animation, depending on the router-link clicked as well? Thanks a lot...

Comment: Oh, that's a little bit different from the original question. In that case I would tell you to create a watch to $router and based on the information from the 'from' and 'to' route decide which transition should be applied dynamically. Documentation has a really good example showing that here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will try to implement what you just described. Thanks a lot for the info!